# How to bring a column that has a DateTime type in SQL Server 2012 into a WCF DataContract C# class?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, wcf

How would you bring a column that has a `DateTime` type in SQL Server 2012 into a WCF DataContract C# class and in a `SqlDataReader`. Would I have to convert it first? Does the fact that it is in an interface make a difference?

The WCF service is my replacement for a `SqlConnection` in an asp.net grid view and I am confused as to all the information about `DateTime` out there and just was wanting to know since from what I've understood so far is that in C# `DateTime` is not considered an actual data type so how would this work.

If I make it into a string it says that it can't do it so what does one do at this point? Thanks for any help you can spare to help understand this as well as helping me see what route I could take.

Frustrated and Clueless,
Lynda

This is my `InvoiceDB` class

```
namespace AbbeyRoadServiceLibrary
{
   [DataObject(true)]
   public class InvoiceDB
   {
      [DataObjectMethod(DataObjectMethodType.Select)]
      public static List<Invoice> GetInvoices(string customerid)
      {
          List<Invoice> invoiceList = new List<Invoice>();

          SqlConnection con = AbbeyRoadDB.GetConnection();

          SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
          cmd.CommandText = "select InvoiceNum,InvoiceDate,InvoiceTotal,Job,Status from Invoices where CustomerID = @CustomerID order by InvoiceNum";
          cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
          cmd.Connection = con;
          cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerID", customerid);

          try
          {
              con.Open();
              SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

              while (reader.Read())
              {
                  Invoice i = new Invoice();
                  i.InvoiceNum = reader[0].ToString();
             // Thought I was to convert it but no happy code results from doing this in this  way!!
                  i.InvoiceDate = Convert.ToDateTime(reader[1]); 
                  i.InvoiceTotal = Convert.ToDecimal(reader[2]);
                  i.Job = reader[3].ToString();
                  i.Status = reader[4].ToString();

                  invoiceList.Add(i);
              }
              reader.Close();
          }
          catch (SqlException ex)
          {
              throw ex;
          }
          finally
          {
              con.Close();
          }

          return invoiceList;
      }
   }
}
```

My interface code primarily just the part that matters!

```
public interface InterfaceInvoiceService
{
    [OperationContract]
    List<Customer> GetCustomer();

    [OperationContract]
    List<Invoice> GetInvoices(string customerid);
}

[DataContract]
public class Invoice
{
    string invoiceID = "";
    string invoicedate = "";  //I know this is not right but see below
    decimal invoicetotal = 0m;
    string job = "";
    string status ="";

    [DataMember]
    public string InvoiceNum
    {
        get { return invoiceID; }
        set { invoiceID = value; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public DateTime InvoiceDate
    {
        get { return invoicedate; } // here it says that it cannot implicitly convert it to a string on return and value.
        set { invoicedate = value; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public decimal InvoiceTotal
    {
        get { return invoicetotal; }
        set { invoicetotal = value; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string Job
    {
        get { return job; }
        set { job = value; }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In C#, `DateTime` *is* a datatype. In addition, you can shorten your code by using [auto-properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx):

```
[DataContract]
public class Invoice
{
    [DataMember]
    public string InvoiceNum { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public DateTime InvoiceDate { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public decimal InvoiceTotal { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Job { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change the datatype of the variable to DateTime as

```
DateTime invoicedate;

[DataMember]
public DateTime InvoiceDate
{
    get { return invoicedate; } 
    set { invoicedate = value; }
}
```